# PowerShell Get-Counter command, -ComputerName vs -Counter

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

Is there a difference between using the -ComputerName parameter and using the path in the -Counter parameter when calling Get-Counter?

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Memory\Available MBytes" -ComputerName \\serv01 
Get-Counter -Counter "\\serv01\Memory\Available MBytes"
```

What reasons are there for choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like by using the `-ComputerName` parameter you can get data from a performance counter from multiple computers in one command, where as by specifying the servername in the counter path you'd need to use a loop or multiple distinct commands.

**Example 5: Get specific counter data from multiple computers**

```
The first command saves the **Disk Reads/sec** counter path in the $DiskReads variable.
PS C:\> $DiskReads = "\LogicalDisk(C:)\Disk Reads/sec"

The second command uses a pipeline operator (|) to send the counter path in the $DiskReads variable to the **Get-Counter** cmdlet. The command uses the **MaxSamples** parameter to limit the output to 10 samples.
PS C:\> $DiskReads | Get-Counter -Computer Server01, Server02 -MaxSamples 10
```

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Memory\Available MBytes" -ComputerName \\serv01
```

This is a generic command, Where you usually know what counter you are referring to and may know or don't know the location.If there are multiple counters of the same name at different locations this will return all of them.And also you can pipe multiple servers in the computername to get-counters on all those servers.

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\\serv01\Memory\Available MBytes"
```

This is a for specific instance where there is only one counter and at a specific location  and you know it.